# Iterating in a sub expression in a here string results in extra spaces, why?

Tags: powershell

### Problem

Running the following in PowerShell version 5.1.15063.726

```
@"
$(foreach ($Number in 1..4) {"$Number`r`n"})
"@
```

results in

```
1
 2
 3
 4
```

There appears to be a trailing space added after the new line for each line.

### Expirments

I thought maybe this was a quirk of

```
`r`n
```

But using `[Environment]::NewLine` has the same issue:

```
@"
$(foreach ($Number in 1..4) {"$Number" + [Environment]::NewLine})
"@

1
 2
 3
 4
```

Doing something seemingly equivelant without iteration works as expected:

```
@"
$("1`r`n" + "2`r`n" + "3`r`n" + "4`r`n")
"@
1
2
3
4
```

The following also work:

```
@"
$("1" + [Environment]::NewLine)$("2" + [Environment]::NewLine)$("3" + [Environment]::NewLine)$("4" + [Environment]::NewLine)
"@

@"
$("1`r`n")$("2`r`n")$("3`r`n")$("4`r`n")
"@
```

The following do not work and result in the odd extra space after the new line:

```
@"
$(1..4 | ForEach-Object {"$_`r`n"})
"@

@"
$(1..4 | ForEach-Object {$("$_`r`n")})
"@
```

### Workaround

Thinking maybe the issue was related to returning multiple strings within the loop I tried to build a single string and then return that form the loop which works:

```
$String = ""
@"
$( foreach ($Number in 1..4) {$String += "$Number`r`n"}; $String)
"@
1
2
3
4
```

If we aggregate the string before returning from the sub expression but do the aggregation outside the loop the same odd behavior comes back:

```
$String = ""
@"
$($String += foreach ($Number in 1..4) {"$Number`r`n"}; $String)
"@

1
 2
 3
 4
```

### Question

Anyone know what is causing this to happen?

Comment: I am wondering what problem you are solving and if there is an alternative approach?

Comment: I would just use `$String = 1..4 -join [Environment]::NewLine`.  I can't think of any reason to embed in a here string like you're doing.

Comment: This is simplified example to show the problem but this bug effects using [PSTemplateEngine](https://github.com/Tervis-Tumbler/PSTemplateEngine/blob/master/PSTemplateEngine.psm1). A simple example would be using a template to generate a [zookeper configuration file](https://github.com/Tervis-Tumbler/TervisKafka/blob/master/KafkaHome/config/zookeeper.properties.pstemplate) that must iterate over an array of zookeeperNodeNames to  create one line per node. It can also process a directory structure of templates substituting all variables,executing arbitrary PowerShell, and outputting the files.

Comment: To provide more context, [this is the function](https://github.com/Tervis-Tumbler/TervisKafka/blob/master/TervisKafka.psm1#L29) that ends up using pstemplate engine to generate the zookeeper config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default output field separator is a space. You should be able to set `$OFS` to an empty string to get the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has to do with the default behavior of the output system:

```
PS C:\> $z = "$(foreach ($Number in 1..4) {"$Number"})"
PS C:\> $z
1 2 3 4
PS C:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($z)
49
32
50
32
51
32
52
PS C:\> $aa = "$(1..4)"
PS C:\> $aa
1 2 3 4
PS C:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($aa)
49
32
50
32
51
32
52
```

32 is the ASCII code for a space.

If you need to do complex string construction, I would use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: is there a more technical name for the output system that would help me find where in the PowerShell source code the thing that is causing this might be? (googling powershell output system didn't come up with anything that looked specific)

Comment: @ChrisMagnuson See @Bill_Stewart's answer about the  default output separator and the `$OFS` automatic variable.  See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`.